# Changing desktops "Workspace Switcher"

Tags: multiple-desktops

Back in 2002 I purchased Suse Linux. The desktop changer was one of the cool features that stood out. It was awesome that I could change desktops with one program here and another on that desktop. It was fast  and it is still the main feature that stands out to me regarding Linux.

Unfortunately the best distro in Linux is the slowest as far as changing desktops.

Is there a way to put a desktop changer"Workspace Switcher" as indicator?

I think that this would be nice. Not as cool as KDE Cube but nice.

Scott.

Comment: Are you talking about the virtual desktops? Why don't you just change it using the hotkeys `Ctrl+Alt+Arrows`?